# Update MySQL database table column only if input(type=file) has any value

Tags: php, mysql

I am updating my DB table column value using HTML form, but the problem is that if I don't put any value in the input field, mysqli_query replace the already existing value with an **empty string**  So I lost that value.

How to make a query that doesn't update the column if input field has no value.
I have done it with if statement but I don't want to use if statement. Can't I do this with only MySQL?

```
if ($post_image) { 
        $query_2 = "UPDATE posts SET post_image = '$post_image' WHERE post_id = $post_id ";
        $editPostImg = mysqli_query($connection, $query_2); 

        if (!$editPostImg) {
            die("Something went wrong.<br>" . mysqli_error($connection));  
        }
    }
```

Comment: could you shar e your code, to see what is wrong with it.

Comment: You have too many unclosed questions already, IMHO anyway.

Comment: @nbk I have updated my question with code... Please have a look again.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner  I have updated my question with code... Please have a look again.

Answer (score -2):

Try changing your query to include a condition about the value you supply.

```
UPDATE posts 
   SET post_image = '$post_image'
 WHERE post_id = $post_id
   AND LENGTH('$post_image') > 0
   AND post_image <>  '$post_image'
```

The second filter item (the first AND) suppresses the update if the value is empty. The third one (the second AND) suppresses it when you change the column value to the value it already has.